# Calculating independence of two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$. $X$ takes the values ${-1,0,1}$ and $Y = X^2$.

I have to determine if these two are independent. I have already calculated that the covariance = 0 for these two random variables.

How do I calculate independence between the two?

Comment: If $Y=0$ then necessariy $X=0$, whereas if $Y=1$, $X \in \{-1,1\}$. The random variables thus cannot possibly be independent.

Comment: If the covariance is $0$, then all this says is that $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated.  This does not necessarily imply independence.

Comment: For a formal proof, use that if $X,Y$ are independent, then $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$. Use that on $X=0,Y=1$.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. But how do I calculate the value of P(X= x, Y = y)? @fgp

Comment: @userunknown Ask yourself it it's possible that $X=0,Y=1$ if $Y=X^2$. Once you've answered that, the joint probability should be obvious.

Comment: @fgp Ah I understand. Y cannot be = 1 when X = 0. So these two cannot be independent.

Comment: @userunknown Yes. Although you have to be a bit carefull. For example $Y=X^2$ *is* independent from $X$ if $X$ is a degenerate random variable that *always* takes the value $0$. Which is why, for a formal proof, it's best to find some joint probability that isn't the product of the individual probabilities, like $P(X=0,Y=1) \neq P(X=0)P(Y=1)$. Here, the LHS is zero, but the RHS is not (assuming that $X=0$ and $Y=1$ have non-zero probability, which they do in your problem)

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$Y \in {0, 1}$, but if $X = 0$, then $Y = 0$ (and $Y$ can't be $1$).
If in some case, some value of $Y$ (in our case = $1$) is not possible due to specific value of $X$ (in our case = $0$), then variables MUST be dependent.